# Open Google Maps to location with NFC tag

Tags: google-maps, nfc

I have an NFC tag containing only one record, in the format of `geo: [latitude],[longitude]`, and when I tap it to my phone the 2 options are the Waze app and Google Maps. Waze opens up to those coordinates just fine, even preparing a route for me instantly, but Google maps just opens like normal, like I just tapped its icon on the launcher and there were never any coordinates.

Am I doing something wrong, or does Google Maps not support that functionality? I've heard of others mentioning this feature but I can't find anyone actually saying whether Google maps is supposed to be able to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps won't show a pin at the location unless you tell it to:

```
geo:0,0?q=34.99,-106.61(Treasure)
```

Read more in the common Android intents documentation:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Maps